# Failed to install OpenUI5 Tooling with npm

Tags: sapui5

This is my first post, excuse if I miss anything.
I am trying to install UI5 tooling to Linux Mint 19.2
Based on the guide at 
https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/GettingStarted/
I am using VS Code as an editor.

I have installed step 1 and step2 but when it comes to step 3 it failed 
at 
npm install @openui5/sap.ui.core @openui5/themelib_sap_belize

So i could not continue working on OpenUI5

Please help me

My npm and node is the latest version for Linux

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the real error output you are seeing, as well as the exact versions of npm and node you are using.

Comment: worked fine here. you did not include the `[...]` from the getting started page, right